# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Database Administrators's [fifth moderator election](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Max Vernon]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Aaron Bertrand who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4861580614303744/0).

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations Max on your election as moderator of the DBA.SE community. I'm looking forward to working with you together with the community.

Comment: thanks very much John!

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations Max! It might be weird to say this as I also applied for the position but you were my first choice as well. The quality and effort you put into this site is what many of us strive to match. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Randi!

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations! You were the obvious candidate. Thank you for stepping up!

Comment: Thanks, Erwin - it was my pleasure.